# Kubernates - mount remote disk (Hetzner Storage Box) on pods

Tags: kubernetes, storage

Imagine having a Pod with the capability to access a remote disk, in this instance, a [Hetzner Storage Box](https://docs.hetzner.com/robot/storage-box/). These types of storage can be accessed using various protocols

- FTP/FTPS
- SAMBA/CIFS
- SFTP/SCP
- SSH/rsync/BorgBackup
- WebDAV

I'm curious if there's a Kubernetes tool or method that would enable me to connect a remote disk to a pod's volume using one of the technologies mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Kubernetes SMB CSI driver.

https://github.com/kubernetes-csi/csi-driver-smb